# How is the location of (a warning in) a multi-line python command determined?

Tags: python, warnings

This code issues four basically identical warnings:

**Update:**

As @Andrew nicely pointed out, the code points at different lines in newer Python versions than when I posted this question four years ago.

In Python 3.11.4, this is the current code and output, which shows that Python always hints at the first line of the offending call:

```py
import warnings

warnings.warn("1")  # warning at this line 3
warnings.warn("2",    # warning at this line 4
              stacklevel=1)

warnings.warn("3",  # warning at this line 7
              )
warnings.warn(  # warning at this line 9
    "4",)

warnings.warn(  # warning at this line 12
    "5",
)
```

Output:

```
C:\Code\project\bug.py:3: UserWarning: 1
  warnings.warn("1")  # warning at this line 3
C:\Code\project\bug.py:4: UserWarning: 2
  warnings.warn("2",    # warning at this line 4
C:\Code\project\bug.py:7: UserWarning: 3
  warnings.warn("3",  # warning at this line 7
C:\Code\project\bug.py:9: UserWarning: 4
  warnings.warn(  # warning at this line 9
C:\Code\project\bug.py:12: UserWarning: 5
  warnings.warn(  # warning at this line 12
```

**Original code:**

```py
import warnings

warnings.warn("1")  # warning at this line 3
warnings.warn("2",
              stacklevel=1)  # warning at this line 5

warnings.warn("3",  # warning at this line 7
              )
warnings.warn(
    "4",)  # warning at this line 10

warnings.warn(
    "5",  # warning at this line 13
)
```

What I have noticed is that the location reported is slightly different:

```
c:\Src\bug.py:3: UserWarning: 1
  warnings.warn("1")  # warning at this line 3
c:\Src\bug.py:5: UserWarning: 2
  stacklevel=1)  # warning at this line 5
c:\Src\bug.py:7: UserWarning: 3
  warnings.warn("3",  # warning at this line 7
c:\Src\bug.py:10: UserWarning: 4
  "4",)  # warning at this line 10
c:\Src\bug.py:13: UserWarning: 5
  "5",  # warning at this line 13
```

In particular, warnings `2` and `4` point to the end line of the command, while warnings `3` and `5` do not (basically, a trailing `)` is ignored). Is this intended? Ideally, I would prefer having the full command shown at the console, not just one line of it.

Comment: The marker will be set onto the last statement of the call.

Comment: @KlausD. sounds like the answer. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2: Python Source Code Snippet

We can look at the [cpython code for warnings.warn()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c1797f661dab563c9b1fa9fdecf2bf1f4d5e0c8e/Lib/warnings.py#L299). First, I'll remove the bits of code not important to the question and I will translate some function calls to the way they could be used in a Python `.py` script.

```python
def warn(message, category=None, stacklevel=1, source=None):
  try:
    if ...:
      ...
    else:
      frame = inspect.currentframe()
      # Look for one frame less since the above line starts us off.
      for x in range(stacklevel-1):
        del x # Unused
        frame = frame.f_back
        if frame is None:
          raise ValueError
  except ValueError:
    ...
    lineno = 1
  else:
    ...
    lineno = frame.f_lineno
  ...
```

For a bit of context on the changes, I took out everything that is not used to designate the lineno. The most notable change is that `sys._getframe(1)` in the cpython source is equivalent to `inspect.currentframe()`. [Here is the source code for inspect.currentframe()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6cb130800554d2582d0e0f63246aa5f16d91e26b/Lib/inspect.py#L1749).

As you can see, if our frame is None (this happens if there is no caller returned in frame.f_back), we have that lineno is 1. Otherwise, we get the first line of the frame we found. This is equivalent to the portion I spoke of below:

> So we have that our line is either the first line of `sys` or the line corresponding to frame `f` as defined by `stacklevel` in `warnings.warn()`.

---

For anyone from the future who finds this question: I did some digging around to find the implementation. For Python 3.11, 3.12.0b, and dev 3.13, `warnings.warn()` locates source code like this:

### Update 1: The answer

The short and sweet of it is that the `warnings` package does not do anything special to get the `lineno` of a multi-line warning. It uses the default value used by [Python Frame objects](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects) and [Python traceback functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#module-traceback).

The latest release version of python **uses the first line of the executed statement**. In Python, those terms have specific definitions. A line is the data between two operating-system-defined newline characters, between BOF and a newline character, or between a newline character and EOF in any file. A statement is a piece of code which causes Python to perform an action (the execution). You can have anywhere from multiple statements in a line of code to no statements in a line of code.

```python
example = []; example.append('this is another statement'); final_statement = 'All 3 of these statements are on one line'
multi_line_example = ('This',
                      'Statement'
                      'Spans'
                      'Multiple'
                      'Lines'
)
# This line is ignored by the Python compiler, it has no statements but is still a line
```

If you want to be pedantic, multi-line strings are technically statements but the code would give a compilation error at run time if you formatted them incorrectly.

#### Clarifying Example

As for what this means in `warnings.warn()`, we can see it in this example:

```python
"""scratch.py"""
import warnings


if __name__ == '__main__':
  warn_alias = warnings.warn
  # <--- This is line 7 of scratch.py --->
  warn_alias('This will return the alias name', #The first LINE of the statement
             # All lines from here to below are not printed






             stacklevel=1 # Trailing parameter
             ) # This is the last LINE of the same statement
```

outputs:

```plaintext
scratch.py:8: UserWarning: This will return the alias name
  warn_alias('This will return the alias name', #The first LINE of the statement

Process finished with exit code 0
```

`warnings.warn()` takes the frame that calls it, moves up the call stack `stacklevel` times (stacklevel=1 uses the frame of the `warnings.warn()` call), and then reads the source line—as written in the corresponding code file—that originated the newly found frame. Note that the source line as written in the file does not necessarily correspond to the full call.

---

### How to Read the Implementation

The above is a high-level interpretation of what goes on under the hood. If you want to see how I got that information or want to check it yourself, here's the process I used:

#### Official Documentation Reference

From [the Python 3.11 documentation for warnings](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/warnings.html), we can find some information on the Warnings Filter:

> The warnings filter controls whether warnings are ignored, displayed, or turned into errors (raising an exception).

So, we know that the warnings filter is the code that determines what is output from a `warnings.warn()` call. Reading a bit more, we find a reference to `lineno`:

> `lineno` is an integer that the line number where the warning occurred must match, or 0 to match all line numbers.

Now we have a reference for how our output layer uses `lineno`. Then, looking at [the documentation for `warnings.warn()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn), we find that the function signature is:

> `warnings.warn(message, category=None, stacklevel=1, source=None)`

#### Referencing the CPython Repository

Since this is an implementation detail, it can change at any point without warning or notice. With that in mind, we can check the codebase for CPython, specifically [the `warnings.py` implementation for Python 3.11](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/34f23904e1e2e683dd6787ee51dd0294ea1f2b11/Lib/warnings.py#L287). Here we find the Python implementation of `warnings.warn()` which performs some *stuff* (you can trace this and figure out the implementation as an exercise). More importantly, we see a comment saying:

> # Code typically replaced by `_warnings`

Now we know that the function is typically replaced by an implementation in C. We can now check out [the file `_warnings.c` for Python 3.11](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/34f23904e1e2e683dd6787ee51dd0294ea1f2b11/Python/_warnings.c#L1202). It's easy enough to find our C equivalent of `warnings.warn()` as `PyErr_Warn()`. We can also take note of the comment:

> /* PyErr_Warn is only for backwards compatibility and will be removed. Use PyErr_WarnEx instead. */

Now we can start tracing where exactly the final output line gets generated. Starting from the mentioned function, we go `PyErr_WarnEx()` > `warn_unicode()` > `do_warn()` > `setup_context()`. [In the definition of `setup_context()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/40d1d28b0729e9c1be21796565821fbbc0f92fdb/Python/_warnings.c#L844), we find:

```c
if (f == NULL) {
    globals = interp->sysdict;
    *filename = PyUnicode_FromString("sys");
    *lineno = 1;
}
else {
    globals = f->f_frame->f_globals;
    *filename = f->f_frame->f_code->co_filename;
    Py_INCREF(*filename);
    *lineno = PyFrame_GetLineNumber(f);
    Py_DECREF(f);
}
```

So we have that our line is either the first line of `sys` or the line corresponding to frame `f` as defined by `stacklevel` in `warnings.warn()`.

Looking at the [header file where `PyFrame_GetLineNumber()` is defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/40d1d28b0729e9c1be21796565821fbbc0f92fdb/Include/pyframe.h#L13), we find a comment that reads: `/* Return the line of code the frame is currently executing. */` and we also have that `PyFrame_GetLineNumber()` is part of the Stable ABI from [the Python C API Reference Manual for Frame Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/frame.html#c.PyFrame_GetLineNumber). Conveniently, the [inspect module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) gives us a look into the frame `lineno` through the documentation for `f_lineno`:

> `f_lineno`: current line number in Python source code

With all this information, we can go back up a level and enter `do_warn()` > `warn_explicit()` > `call_show_warning()` > `show_warning()`. [The declaration of `show_warning()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/40d1d28b0729e9c1be21796565821fbbc0f92fdb/Python/_warnings.c#L495) is well-documented; the function is essentially a giant print() statement. Since we do not pass an explicit `sourceline` when calling `warnings.warn()`, our lookup is as follows:

```c
static void
show_warning(PyThreadState *tstate, PyObject *filename, int lineno,
             PyObject *text, PyObject *category, PyObject *sourceline)
{
    ...
    if (sourceline) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        _Py_DisplaySourceLine(f_stderr, filename, lineno, 2, NULL, NULL);
    }
    ...
}
```

`_Py_DisplaySourceLine()` essentially opens the file from which our frame originated, reads the line, and outputs it to a stream.

With that, we have all the parts of the puzzle figured out.

Comment: I think I am missing the part where you actually answer the question ;) my question was specifically about multiline commands and which line of those will be used to determine the line number. KlausD suggested it is "the last statement of the call". Can you confirm that with your analysis?

Comment: Hey bers, thanks for the feedback. I added a more explicit explanation of *how* the line number is gotten and improved my example. Let me know if there's anything confusing.

As a preface, I don't mean to sound pedantic or be rude in any way. To answer the question in your comment, there is only one statement per call in Python—there isn't a first or "last". You can read more about what a call is in the [C documentation for Python call Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html).

The line number used is the first line containing any piece of the current statement.

Comment: "The line number used is the first line containing any piece of the current statement." So the closing parenthesis is not "any piece ..."?

Comment: @bers: [PEP626](https://peps.python.org/pep-0626/#the-f-lineno-attribute) specifically defines what `lineno` is. In the case of `warnings`, "The f_lineno attribute will be updated to match the line number about to be executed, even if tracing is turned off and no event is generated." is the point of interest. No code is executed by the closing parenthesis by itself so `lineno` would not get updated. One thing to note is that PEP626 was approved and implemented after this question was posted. The line returned by `warnings` is now defined differently.

Answer (score 0):

## Update 1: Warning Utilising `traceback`

After checking out the Python source code again, I ended up writing a function to programmatically get a statement spanning multiple lines. Here's the script I made:

```python
"""using_the_callstack.py"""
import inspect
import itertools
import warnings
from collections.abc import Iterator


getframeinfo_context_adjustment = 2


def get_frameinfo_from_callstack(stacklevel: int = 1):
  call_stack = inspect.stack(context=0)
  try:
    frameinfo = call_stack[stacklevel]
  except IndexError:
    frameinfo = call_stack[-1]
  return frameinfo


def get_traceback(frameinfo: inspect.FrameInfo,
                  ) -> tuple[inspect.Traceback, int]:
  position_in_file = frameinfo.positions
  expected_line_count = (position_in_file.end_lineno -
                         position_in_file.lineno + 1)
  expected_line_count *= getframeinfo_context_adjustment
  return (inspect.getframeinfo(frameinfo.frame, expected_line_count),
          expected_line_count)


def extract_statement_from_source(traceback: inspect.Traceback,
                                  expected_line_count: int,
                                  ) -> Iterator[str]:
  if len(traceback.code_context) == expected_line_count:
    code_start = expected_line_count // getframeinfo_context_adjustment
  else:
    # lineno is 1-indexed, traceback.code_context is 0-indexed
    code_start = traceback.lineno - 1
  code = itertools.islice(traceback.code_context,
                          code_start,
                          None)
  return itertools.chain(code)


def send_multiline_warning(message: Warning | str,
                           category: type[Warning],
                           stacklevel: int = 1,
                           ) -> None:
  frameinfo = get_frameinfo_from_callstack(stacklevel)
  traceback, expected_line_count = get_traceback(frameinfo)
  code = extract_statement_from_source(traceback, expected_line_count)
  warnings.showwarning(message=message,
                       category=category,
                       filename=traceback.filename,
                       lineno=traceback.lineno,
                       line=''.join(code))
```

The implementation ended up being fairly convoluted so I decomposed it into a few functions. `send_multiline_warning()` is the important piece here, its signature is the same as the first three parameters of `warnings.warn()`

---

I am including this as a separate answer since the scope of this answer and [my other answer explaining the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76426576/21927427) ended up going in two different directions.

Here are some example scripts that output warnings containing multiple lines.

```python
"""custom_warning_formatting.py"""
import inspect
import warnings


if __name__ == '__main__':
  multiple_lines, _ = inspect.getsourcelines(inspect.currentframe())
  multiple_lines = ''.join(multiple_lines[9:15])  # Remember lists are 0-indexed
  # <--- This is line 9 of custom_warning_formatting.py --->
  warnings.showwarning(message='This warning has a custom line',
                       category=UserWarning,
                       filename=f'This can be a custom string or {__file__}',
                       lineno=-2147483648,
                       file=None,  # Optional write warning to file
                       line=multiple_lines)
  warnings.showwarning(message='This warning reads from file',
                       category=UserWarning,
                       filename=__file__,
                       lineno=23,
                       file=None,  # Optional write warning to file
                       line=None)
# <--- This is line 22 of custom_warning_formatting.py --->
# If line is None, and filename and lineno are valid, the function will print the line referenced
```

which generates the following output:

```plaintext
This can be a custom string or scratch.py:-2147483648: UserWarning: This warning has a custom line
  warnings.showwarning(message='This warning has a custom line',
                       category=UserWarning,
                       filename=f'This can be a custom string or {__file__}',
                       lineno=-2147483648,
                       file=None,  # Optional write warning to file
                       line=multiple_lines)
scratch.py:23: UserWarning: This warning reads from file
  # If line is None, and filename and lineno are valid, the function will print the line referenced

Process finished with exit code 0
```

An alternative method which does not require hardcoding line numbers (but requires a regex pattern):

```python
"""programmatically_extracting_source_code.py"""
import inspect
import re
import warnings


# <--- This is line 7 of programmatically_extracting_source_code.py --->
def example_function():
  return ('Action '
          'causing '
          'the warning '
          'happens in these lines')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  source_code, start_of_scope = inspect.getsourcelines(example_function)
  source_code = ''.join(source_code)
  p = re.compile(r".*\('[\s\S]+'\).*")
  code_of_interest = p.search(source_code)
  warnings.showwarning(message='This warning uses regex to get source code',
                       category=UserWarning,
                       filename=__file__,
                       lineno=start_of_scope,
                       file=None,  # Optional write warning to file
                       line=code_of_interest.group())
```

this outputs:

```plaintext
scratch.py:8: UserWarning: This warning uses regex to get source code
  return ('Action '
          'causing '
          'the warning '
          'happens in these lines')

Process finished with exit code 0
```

## Process

The original question asks about the nature of `warnings.warn()`. However, the same behaviour also shows up in all other packages that make use of [Python's Traceback package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#module-traceback). For example, here is a `builtin` exception:

```python
raise ValueError('Exceptions also only show one line of code '
                 'But we tend not to notice because one line is usually '
                 'enough')
```

which generates the following output:

```plaintext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Exceptions also only show one line of code '
ValueError: Exceptions also only show one line of code But we tend not to notice because one line is usually enough
```

> Ideally, I would prefer having the full command shown at the console, not just one line of it.

To get the desired behaviour, we need to reach into the other toolkits Python provides.

## Returning a Multiline Warning

### Step 1: Get the Source Code

Since warning will not give us multiple lines (this is a behaviour from `Traceback`), we first start by getting the multiple lines ourselves. There are a lot of methods to read in files, but I'll focus on some methods from [the Python inspect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) and one using [the os.path module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path):

```python
"""finding_source_code.py"""
import os.path
import inspect


# You can obtain the source code of the current file in a couple of ways:
list_of_source_lines, start_of_scope_for_this_statement_lineno = (
  inspect.getsourcelines(inspect.currentframe())
)

source_as_one_string = inspect.getsource(inspect.currentframe())

THIS_FILE_PATH = os.path.abspath(__file__)
with open(THIS_FILE_PATH, encoding='utf-8') as f:
  source_lines_without_trailing_whitespace = [line.rstrip() for line in f]


# Or a module like this:
module_source_code = inspect.getsource(inspect)


def generic_function(param1, param2, *args, **kwargs):
  pass
# or you can get the source code for a specific function like this
function_source = inspect.getsource(generic_function)
```

As a disclaimer, there are almost certainly more efficient ways to read in the file source code. However, these will work just fine for our purposes.

### Step 2: Identify the Function We Will Use

From the `warnings` module, we can use the function [`warnings.showwarning()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html?highlight=warnings#warnings.showwarning). In particular, this function lets us specify the parameter `line`. From the documentation, we have:

> line is a line of source code to be included in the warning message; if line is not supplied, showwarning() will try to read the line specified by filename and lineno.

Although the documentation states "...a line of source code...", we can actually get away with passing an arbitrarily long string. Now, we have a tool that looks and acts like warning. All that's left is...

### Step 3: Raising a Custom Warning

By combining the information obtained in Step 1 with the function introduced in Step 2, I made a small example script. The first call to `warnings.showwarning()` uses lines from some source code to form `line`. The second call to `warnings.showwarning()` behaves like `warning.warn()` but points to a specific line instead of emitting the line generating the warning.

## Alternative (but more involved) Approach:

For working with functions in the call stack, things get complicated as you must use `traceback` to parse through function calls. However, this also gives you a lot lower level control.

The actual process for this goes outside the scope of the question, but [here is an answered Stack Overflow question showing a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39043790/21927427).

Comment: I still don't get it. Where is the part of the Python code that determines which line number of a multi-line statement gets printed? How does it ignore the closing parentheses but not everything else?

Comment: @bers: That is a bit outside of the scope of this question since it focused on warnings.warn(). If you want to know the implementation details, I would recommend making a new question specifically about [pycore_frame](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/internal/pycore_frame.h). If you just want to check out what the call stack (that is, all the calls and each method) looks like, you can use `inspect.stack()` to see a trace of all the calls.

Comment: Forgive me, but I find it rather odd that you try to (re-)define the scope of the question I asked. The code example in the question specifically uses `warnings.warn` and nothing else.

Comment: @bers: Ah, I see where I misunderstood now. Your code example no longer returns the same values that are posted in the question. In a version change (I believe it was 3.10, but I am not 100%) CPython's frames define line numbers differently. Since `warnings` uses CPython frames to return the line numbers, this change made `warn()` return different values. --- The reason I recommended checking out `inspect` is that the inspect package is the official module for interacting with implementation written in C. Specifically, it lets you interact with `Frame` objects (which contain the `f_lineno`).

Comment: @bers: There is also [a section in PEP626 which goes over tracing changes](https://peps.python.org/pep-0626/#example-event-sequences). This is probably the closest we can get to official documentation for this kind of thing. If you really want to get into it, the `Warning` class is a subclass of `Exception`. The change specifically modified behaviour implemented under the `Exception` class.